# How to get an attribute on a Drawable resource on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I want to basically create a 'support' version of the API 21+ `tint` xml attribute. How can I get the `tint` attribute (or a custom attribute) from the drawable, in code, without using a custom `View` for every image?

Here is the /res/drawable/brandable_icon_slider_featured.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tintns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:src="@drawable/brandable_icon_slider_featured_img"
    tintns:tintColor="@color/branded_menu" />
```

I then created a custom `Resources` subclass and use that in my Activities.

```
public class CustomResource extends Resources {
    ...

    @Override
    public XmlResourceParser getXml(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        XmlResourceParser parser = super.getXml(id);
        return parser;
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawableForDensity(int id, int density) throws NotFoundException {
        return replaceWithTintableBitmap(super.getDrawableForDensity(id, density));
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawableForDensity(int id, int density, Theme theme) {
        return replaceWithTintableBitmap(super.getDrawableForDensity(id, density, theme));
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        return replaceWithTintableBitmap(super.getDrawable(id));
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(int id, Theme theme) throws NotFoundException {
        return replaceWithTintableBitmap(super.getDrawable(id, theme));
    }

    private Drawable replaceWithTintableBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if(drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return new TintableBitmap(this, (BitmapDrawable) drawable);
        }

        return drawable;
    }
}
```

and, of course, my `TintableBitmap` class extends `BitmapDrawable` and it will 'transform' the `tint` attribute into a `drawable.setColorFilter` call, which has backwards support.

I tried using a custom attribute to no avail.

```
<!-- attrs.xml -->
<declare-styleable name="TintTheme">
    <attr name="tintColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
<!-- themes.xml -->
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="tintColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

So, is it possible to detect and get the value of the `tint` attribute, either in `CustomResource` or in `TintableBitmap`?

Comment: sorry,  you cannot do that

Comment: It's not possible without using a _lot_ of reflection in order to call hidden/private methods, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Ah, disappointing. I was hoping that getXml would get me something with the xml text that I could search, but no dice. I'll keep away from reflection hackery and try another approach to my core problem. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you _can_ create your own method to parse the specific bitmap XML files using one of the `openXmlResourceParser()` methods in `AssetManager`, but you can't implement a complete replacement for the `Resources` functionality that automatically handles this using the same API without using reflection, and you would have to re-implement the caching and other optimizations that are performed by the existing implementation.